# How can I set an appBar title Image to another image based on light/dark mode?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I'm trying to enable a dark mode image variant when the dark mode has been toggled on and a light background image when light has been enabled. Is there any way to do that in flutter

```
           onTap: () {
          if (Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark) {
            setBrightness(Brightness.light);
            setting.value.brightness.value = Brightness.light;
            AppBar(
              title: Image.asset('assets/img/gc.png', height: 100,));
          } else {
            setting.value.brightness.value = Brightness.dark;
            setBrightness(Brightness.dark);
            AppBar(
              title: Image.asset('assets/img/cgold.png', height: 100,),);
          }
          setting.notifyListeners();
```

**((WORKING SOLUTIOM))**

```
    title: Image.asset(Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
        ? ('assets/img/gold.png')
        : ('assets/img/white.png'), height: 100,),
```

This was simply placed in the appBar widget :)

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if this works

```
bool light = true;

...
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(theme: light = true ? ThemeData.light() : ThemeData.dark(),
      ...
      AppBar(
              title: light = true ? Image.asset('assets/img/gc.png', height: 100,) : Image.asset('assets/img/cgold.png', height: 100,),)
      ...
    );
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately no luck :(

Comment: Make sure its a stateful widget class and on the tap function wrap it with setState